# How to receive parse notification data in ParsePushBroadcastReceiver or ParseBraodcastReceiver of Inactive app?

Tags: android, parse-platform

### Manifest File

> I include following receiver

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
```

> This is was MyParseService extending ParseBroadcastReceiver

```
    <receiver android:name=".MyParseReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            <action android:name="com.wattabyte.detectivecamparse.UPDATE_STATUS" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name=".DetectiveCamPushReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            <action android:name="com.wattabyte.detectivecamparse.UPDATE_STATUS" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

### MyParseReceiver class

> This Class is subclass of ParsePushBroadcastReceiver
>   Here tried with onReceivemethod to get notification

```
public class MyParseReceiver extends ParseBroadcastReceiver {
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
        if (intent == null)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Receiver intent null");
        }
        else
        {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.d(TAG, "got action " + action );
            if (action.equals("com.wattabyte.detectivecamparse.UPDATE_STATUS"))
            {
                String channel = intent.getExtras().getString("Wattabyte");
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));

                Log.d(TAG, "got action " + action + " on channel " + channel + " with:");
                Iterator itr = json.keys();
                while (itr.hasNext()) {
                    String key = (String) itr.next();

            Log.d(TAG, "..." + key + " => " + json.getString(key));
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

### DetectiveCamPushReceiver

> This is ParsePushBroadcastReceiverClass
>   I tried with on Push Receive and on Push open

```
 @Override
protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Implement
    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    JSONObject data = getDataFromIntent(intent);
    // Do something with the data. To create a notification do:
        Log.e("Vinay",""+data.toString());
    if (data != null){
        Log.e("MSG","Data pushed from parse");
    }


    // OPTIONAL create soundUri and set sound:


}

private JSONObject getDataFromIntent(Intent intent) {
    JSONObject data = null;
    try {
        data = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString(PARSE_DATA_KEY));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // Json was not readable...

    }
    return data;
}
```

> Help me out to read from **ParsePush** data **background activity**
>
> Thanks in advance
>   Any Help would be appreciated